# How to store in a php variable data from innerHTML when happens

Tags: php, ajax, websocket

I have a websocket script that looks in blockchain to a specific address if someone sends btc. If the payment is done, the script will output with javascript innerHTML a message. Is there a way I can make to run a php script if this happens? Script below

```js
<script>

                var btcs = new WebSocket("wss:ws.blockchain.info/inv");

                btcs.onopen = function(){
                    btcs.send(JSON.stringify({"op":"addr_sub", "addr":<?php echo json_encode($new_address, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>}));
                    };
                btcs.onmessage = function(onmsg) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(onmsg.data);
                    var getOuts = response.x.out;
                    var countOuts = getOuts.length;

                    for(i=0; i<countOuts; i++){
                    var outAdd = response.x.out(i).addr;
                    var address = <?php echo json_encode($new_address, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
                    if(outAdd == address){
                        var amount = response.x.out(i).value;
                        var recAmount = amount / 100000000;
                        document.getElementByid("websocket").innerHTML = "Payment recieved: " + recAmount + "BTC <br>; 
                        };
                    };
                }; 
                </script>
```

```html
<p id="websocket">Monitoring transaction...</p>
```

Comment: You already have the answer as one of your tags. Ajax. Do some research on that and give it a try.

Comment: I know ajax can handle this, but I have no experience in Ajax, I've search a lot but nothing good for me...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started